# jQuery Re-run script on ajax loaded content

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am using the **[Advanced Ajax Page Loader](http://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-ajax-page-loader/)** plugin for wordpress to load content via ajax, and I am having an issue with my custom jquery scripts not running on content when they are loaded via ajax. The scripts run fine if I load said pages directly from their url, but navigating to them via ajax loads causes them to not work.

an example script I am using is

```
var o = {
    init: function(){
        this.diagram();
    },
    random: function(l, u){
        return Math.floor((Math.random()*(u-l+1))+l);
    },
    diagram: function(){
        var r = Raphael('diagram', 600, 600),
            rad = 73,
            defaultText = 'Skills',
            speed = 250;

        r.circle(300, 300, 85).attr({ stroke: 'none', fill: 'rgba(0,0,0,.10)' });

        var title = r.text(300, 300, defaultText).attr({
            font: '14px ralewaylight',
            fill: '#fff'
        }).toFront();

        r.customAttributes.arc = function(value, color, rad){
            var v = 3.6*value,
                alpha = v == 360 ? 359.99 : v,
                random = o.random(91, 100),
                a = (random-alpha) * Math.PI/180,
                b = random * Math.PI/180,
                sx = 300 + rad * Math.cos(b),
                sy = 300 - rad * Math.sin(b),
                x = 300 + rad * Math.cos(a),
                y = 300 - rad * Math.sin(a),
                path = [['M', sx, sy], ['A', rad, rad, 0, +(alpha > 180), 1, x, y]];
            return { path: path, stroke: color }
        }

        jQuery('.get').find('.arc').each(function(i){
            var t = jQuery(this), 
                color = t.find('.color').val(),
                value = t.find('.percent').val(),
                text = t.find('.text').text();

            rad += 30;  
            var z = r.path().attr({ arc: [value, color, rad], 'stroke-width': 20 });

            z.mouseover(function(){
                this.animate({ 'stroke-width': 30, opacity: 1 }, 1000, 'elastic');
                if(Raphael.type != 'VML') //solves IE problem
                this.toFront();
                title.stop().animate({ opacity: 0 }, speed, '>', function(){
                    this.attr({ text: text + '\n' + value + '%' }).animate({ opacity: 1 }, speed, '<');
                });
            }).mouseout(function(){
                this.stop().animate({ 'stroke-width': 20, opacity: 1 }, speed*4, 'elastic');
                title.stop().animate({ opacity: 0 }, speed, '>', function(){
                    title.attr({ text: defaultText }).animate({ opacity: 1 }, speed, '<');
                }); 
            });
        });

    }
}
jQuery(function(){ o.init(); });
```

I understand you can use **.delegate** for click functions, but this does not help with non-click functions.

Side note: the plugin comes with a "reload code" feature, and any script I paste in appears as reloaded in the console but doesn't actually function.

Comment: Try replacing ".on" with ".live"

Comment: @Afreen - this is poor advice. `on` replaced `live` (now deprecated) quite a while ago

Answer (score 0):

Try this:`$(document).on('click', 'a[href^="#"]', function...`

Comment: I need a solution for non-click functions in particular

Comment: What means "non-click functions"? Write any example.

Comment: Seems like you should run `o.init();` after loading page by ajax.